# Conjugate of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Can you guys please tell that what's the conjugate of $i^i$?
I tried to solve on the basis that multiplying conjugate with it's respective complex no. yields real no. So my try gives its answer as $i^{-i}$.
Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).

Comment: Can you use $i = e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$?

Comment: Do you realize that there are infinitely many values of $i^i?$

Comment: Because $i = e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)}$ for any integer k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short, hand-wavy answer

$$
\overline{i^i}={\overline i}^{\overline i}=(1/i)^{-i}=i^i
$$
so the  conjugate of $i^i$ is itself. I should mention that I got this trick from a different answer on this site, but I do not remember which one.

#### Rigorous answer

The definition of $z^w$ is $\exp(w\log z)=\exp(w(\log |z|+i\arg(z))$. This is a multivalued funciton, because $\text{arg}$ is multivalued, since it is only well defined up to a multiple of $2\pi$. Therefore,
$$
i^i=\exp(i(\log |i|+i\arg i))=\exp(-(\pi/2+2\pi k)),
$$
where the above equation is valid for any $k\in \mathbb Z$. No matter which $k$ you choose, the result is real, so the conjugate of $i^i$ is always itself.

Answer (score 1):

We can compute $i^i=e^{\frac{-\pi}{2}+2k\pi}, k \in \Bbb Z$ .

What is worth noting is that, despite it being a highly irrational number, all values of $i^i$ are real - they don't have a complex conjugate, or at the very least, its conjugate is itself (I don't know for certain which is the better definition).